# function using ifelse to group_by and summarise with dplyr throwing unused argument error

Tags: r

I am trying to create function that includes two arguments. The first is a categorical grouping variable and the second is an analysis variable. The function will first take the categorical variable and ensure that it is a character variable and then take the analysis variable and ensure that it is numeric. Then it will group the variables by the grouping variable and take the sum of the numeric variable. Finally, it will organize from small to large and generate a .csv file. I am using the diamonds dataset.

```
cut <- c('Ideal', 'Premium', 'Ideal', 'Premium')
carat <- c(12, 10, 12, 10)
diamonds <- data.frame(cut, carat)
```

The code for my function is:

```
analyzed_dataframe <- function(grouping_variable, analysis_variable) {
  if(is.numeric(grouping_variable) & is.character(analysis_variable)) {
      break
    } else {
      dplyr::group_by(grouping_variable) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(total_variable = sum(analysis_variable))
      order(analyzed_dataframe$analysis_variable, decreasing = TRUE)
      write.csv(analyzed_dataframe, 'analyzed_df.csv')
    }
}
```

When I run the function,  `analyzed_dataframe(cut, carat)` I get the error message:

```
Error in analyzed_dataframe(., clarity, carat) : unused argument (carat)
```

I'm getting the sense that it is something within the else statement because the if statement ran fine. I'll also add that the function itself doesn't throw an error when I create it. The error is only thrown when I try to use it. Are there any glaring issues?

Comment: To run the function, would you write: analyzed_dataframe(diamonds$carat, diamonds$cut) ?

Comment: When I run it like that, I get the following error:                  Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Sorry, I should have phrased by question differently - what I meant was is carat the grouping variable and cut the analysis variable?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Please could you edit the question with the code you are running that yields the error you want to fix.

Comment: I added the way that I ran the function.